# Fern-wifi-cracker won't install

Tags: command-line

So i tried to install Fern wifi cracker but it won't let me install it and i get this;

```
root@john:~/Desktop# dpkg -i Fern-Wifi-Cracker_1.6_all.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package fern-wifi-cracker.
(Reading database ... 251856 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fern-wifi-cracker (from Fern-Wifi-Cracker_1.6_all.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fern-wifi-cracker:
 fern-wifi-cracker depends on aircrack-ng; however:
  Package aircrack-ng is not installed.
dpkg: error processing fern-wifi-cracker (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fern-wifi-cracker
root@john:~/Desktop#
```

Anyone know how i can solve this problem please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install aircrack-ng first from the repositories (Synaptic or Ubuntu Software Center, what you prefer). Then try to install fern-wifi-cracker again.

Comment: I already have aircrack-ng installed

Comment: It still won't let me install it though

Comment: what i'd do is to uninstall them completely, using Synaptic, reboot and install them again.